# Starting a blank console

Tags: java, console

IS there any way to start a blank console in Windows platform ?

I'm writing a CLI where i want to open a separate window where user can log in and write their own command. When executing with **cmd /c start** command, it starts windows standard console.

Is there any other command ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to start a java jar file, use a command like this:

```
start /d "%~dp0" java -jar "%~dp0\fpa.jar"
```

%~dp0 expands to the drive letter and path in which the batch file is located.  Use that if you want to want to make sure that the PWD when running is the same location as the batch file.  Otherwise, juse use

```
start java -jar "%~dp0\fpa.jar"
```

This will make sure that the batch file works even if you run it when not in the same directory as the jar file, as long as the jar file is in the same directory as the batch file.

You may need to make sure that java is in your path by having a line like

```
set path=jre6\bin;%PATH%
```

Also, you can eliminate the command line windows that comes up (for a GUI program by example) by using `javaw` instead of `java`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch file in windows which would in turn start application that would accept user input. Something similar to this :

> start cmd /c myapp.bat